# In R - How do I plot the data from the row where the date=='"2020 Q1' to the last row of the dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts, linechart

example of the data:

| Date | Inflation |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 Q1 | 2 |
| 2020 Q2 | 2.1 |
| 2020 Q3 | 2 |
| 2020 Q4 | 2.1 |

I am using ggplot `ggplot(CPI,aes(x=date,y=inflation,group=1))+geom_line()` but I would like to only plot from whichever row number that contains date= 2020 Q1 until the last row of the set (which will change everytime as I am getting webscraping the data from a website).

Comment: I'd include all of your code and data to make a reproducible example. That said, it might be that you need to use `filter` from `dplyr` on your CPI data before you get to the `ggplot` call

Comment: Try `ggplot(which(CPI$Date == "2020 Q1"):nrow(CPI),], ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! I have followed the advice to cut the data before the  `ggplot` call, and I also used `which` and `nrow`. It no works:                                    
`cut_cpi<- cpi[(which(cpi$date=="2020 JAN")):nrow(cpi),]` and `ggplot(cut_cpi,aes(x=date,y=inflation, group=1))+geom_line()`